# New Job, Chaotic Work Environment, Too Many Conflicting Priorities

Tags: communication, deadlines

I've just started a new job as a EA (Executive Assistant) and at a high salary.  The thing is, I'm expected to take on a business development role, the HR function, recruitment and training of staff, the project management and launch of a new office, plus do my regular EA role.

In addition, there is no set out procedures or definable work flow.  I'm also expected to set up these processes.  All priorities given to me are not clearly defined and I have not been given any orientation of the business.  Priorities are thrown out daily and when I have tried to point out that other priorities will be thrown out, my immediate supervisor seems not to hear what I have said.

I see more clarification on some tasks but since my boss is so busy, you will fob me off.  I can't seem to tie him down. How do I sort out this chaos?

Comment: Basically you think peoples are pushing too much responsabilities on you and so too much works ? Have you ask to HR ?

Answer (score 6):

I am thinking it's possible that they want you to sort out the priorities or take charge a bit.

What you could do is list all your tasks and prioritise how you think they should be. Any tasks you need clarification on will be low priority if you can't start working on them, so note this on the list.

Send this as an email to your boss, and tell him that you are currently assuming these are the priorities, and will start working thusly, asking if this is correct. Also tell him there is outstanding clarification required on the noted items and if applicable you that you can't start working on them until the clarification is received.

He will either come back to you asking you to change it, agree with it, or not come back at all. If he doesn't come back, just start working per your own list.

If he complains later on, you have the email you sent as evidence to back you up.

If you get everything you can done and still haven't got clarification on the remaining items, you'll have to start chasing him, and tell him you have nothing to do until he clarifies. Again by email.

Comment: not sure about the first point, but yes i strongly agree : have a **writing** copy of all the decision you/your supervisor make and all stuff you're charged too.